# Hazelcast AWS ECS takes 5 minutes (300 seconds) to find members

Tags: hazelcast, amazon-ecs, vert.x

I am running a Java program Vert.x with **Hazelcast** 3.10.5 on AWS ECS using hazelcast-aws plugin. For old hazelcast version (3.8) it worked fine, but with new version, it took **5** minutes (**300** seconds) to find other members. Locally, it can immediately join other members.

- Here is configuration xml file.

```
<aws enabled="false">
</aws>
<discovery-strategies>
  <discovery-strategy
        enabled="true" class="com.hazelcast.aws.AwsDiscoveryStrategy">
      <properties>
        <property name="iam-role">my-iam-role</property>
        <property name="region">us-west-2</property>
        <property name="host-header">ec2.amazonaws.com</property>
        <property name="tag-key">myCluster</property>
        <property name="tag-value">myValue</property>
      </properties>
  </discovery-strategy>
</discovery-strategies>
</join>
<interfaces enabled="true">
  <interface>10.10.*.*</interface>
</interfaces>
```

- Here is log

```
    11:30:00 2019-08-01T18:30:00,090 [INFO ] LifecycleService: - [10.10.2.41]:5709 [dev] [3.10] [10.10.2.41]:5709 is STARTING
    11:30:00 2019-08-01T18:30:00,161 [INFO ] system: - [10.10.2.41]:5709 [dev] [3.10] Cluster version set to 3.10
    11:30:00 2019-08-01T18:30:00,162 [INFO ] ClusterService: - [10.10.2.41]:5709 [dev] [3.10]
    Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [10.10.2.41]:5709 - 1be4ca1e-4792-4d3a-a960-e73ad073e2a6 this]

    11:35:00 2019-08-01T18:35:00,442 [INFO ] TcpIpConnectionManager: - [10.10.2.41]:5709 [dev] [3.10] Established socket connection between /10.10.2.41:37510 and /10.10.2.41:5710

    Members {size:2, ver:2} [
    Member [10.10.2.41]:5709 - 1be4ca1e-4792-4d3a-a960-e73ad073e2a6 this
    Member [10.10.2.41]:5710 - 813f9154-e8e3-4c82-83b4-6921ec80519b]
```

As you can see, **5 minutes** later, 11:35 it established connection.

Comment: When you tag your instances, how much time do you wait before start Hazelcast members? I remember there was some (relatively long) propagation time for EC2 Instance tags.

Comment: I use ECS update-service, so EC2 instance is already there, shouldn't caused by this problem.

Comment: It's weird. It should discover other nodes all of the sudden. Looks like a bug to me. Could you maybe create an issue (with the steps to reproduce) here: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-aws. Thanks!

Comment: I have already created an issue. Currently, the only way is to keep Hazelcast version as **3.8.2**. As long as the version is 3.10+ or later, on AWS it needs 300 seconds to join others